# Jmeter Constant Timer Causing Errors

Tags: timer, jmeter

I have setup a simple jmeter test with 150 threads, a constant timer of 7 seconds and an http request.
If I increase the constant timer to a 100 seconds, then the http request starts throwing an error. The error says "Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException,Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond"

Has anyone encountered this? What could be the root cause?

Comment: Is the connection timed out? Is keepalive used?

Comment: I am using http request, as far as i know, jmeter does not allow the keepalive for http request.

Comment: It does.http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Comment: Disable keepalive or increase the limit on the server and please rerun.

Comment: Ok I found the keepalive setting. Thanks. However, even after disabling the "Use KeepAlive" setting, I am still getting errors.

Comment: I basically added another dummy call that will throw an error and reset the connection. That seems to have solved the problem. Thank you for your help though. The important thing to know was that the connection should not be kept alive...doesn't matter what method you use to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you're facing the issue which is described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) JMeter Wiki page.

> Enabling retry
>
> For HttpClient 4, in user.properties set :
>
> httpclient4.retrycount=1 This will make JMeter retry once. For
>   HttpClient 3, in user.properties set:
>
> httpclient3.retrycount=1 This will make JMeter retry once.
>
> Enabling stale check
>
> For HC4 Implementation:
>
> In user.properties:
>
> hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters In hc.parameters set:
>
> http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true For HC3 Implementation:
>
> In user.properties:
>
> httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters In
>   httpclient.parameters set:
>
> http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for the most appropriate option for above properties setting/overriding.